# Modelling probability distribution of a set of sequences (to calculate Entropy)

Tags: distributions, modeling, hidden-markov-model, entropy, sequential-pattern-mining

Let $T$ be a set of trajectories $\tau$, where $\tau=\{\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,...\mathbf{x}_N\}$ with $\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^k$ being a vector of observations.

I am looking for an efficient and good way to model a probability distribution $p(T)$, which could then be used to calculate its entropy: $h(T)= -\int p(T) \ln p(T)$

The basic way, I guess, would be to treat each trajectory as an independent distribution, and model a joint probability as:

$p(T)=p(\tau_1,...,\tau_T)=\prod_{i=1}^Tp(\tau_i)$

Where each $p(\tau)$ can be modelled as:

$p(\tau)=p(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,...\mathbf{x}_N)=p(\mathbf{x}_1)\prod_{i=2}^Np(\mathbf{x}_i|\mathbf{x}_{i-1})$

I was thinking of modelling $p(\mathbf{x})$ as a multivariate Gaussian, or maybe some other exponential-family (or energy-based) distribution, which doesn't have too many parameters, so that they can be obtained via EM or MLE.

However, if I apply the log to get log-probabilities the integrals would be intractable and I would need to rely on some approximate inference approaches.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: You   might take a look at [Shannon entropy](http://bearcave.com/misl/misl_tech/wavelets/compression/shannon.html), just to get a look at some of what has been done as well as [KL-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).

Comment: I agree that Shannon entropy and KL can be used to measure entropy, but they require a probability density function. The part which I am having problems grasping is how to get this pdf from a set of sequences.

Comment: Shannon entropy is self-referential, in other words it is not absolute entropy. Any question about absolute entropy needs to integrate specific heat  (energy per unit mass per degree temperture) over the total range of temperature (energy transfer break even)  for a given mass. The equation for pdf fitting to data is data $=\kappa$ pdf, where $\kappa=$ AUC and AUC is total  area under the curve.